# PHP laravel Authorize.net

Tags: php, laravel, authorize.net

I am trying integrate Authorize.net with a laravel app, to accept onetime payments. I have gone through the authorize.net's php library on [GitHub](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-php), and I see charge-credit-card.php is expecting credit card details as input.

Questions:

1. Is it okay to ask for credit card no.s directly as a form? (Perhaps over a https)
2. I would like to redirect user to Authorize.net rather than collecting the credit card details on my site.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways that would enable you to reduce your PCI compliance requirements would be to use either [Accept.js](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/acceptjs.html)  or [Accept Hosted](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/accept_hosted.html).